# Regex to not allow space between words

Tags: regex, reactjs

I wrote the following logic for my input field.

```
      handlevalidFunctionalityName(e) {
        let value = e.target.value.trim();
        if (value != "") {
          let pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9-_\s])*$/;

          if (pattern.test(value)) {
            this.setState({ validFunctionalityName: false });
          } else {
            this.setState({ validFunctionalityName: true });
          }
        }
      }
```

This input field should not support any special character except underscore and hyphen. Also, i don't want it to allow space between the words. Means entered string should be a single word. No space should be allowed before, after, or in between the string.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$/`

Comment: You should try to change your final `\s` to `\S` : `\S = anything except a whitespace (newline, tab, space)`